# Why does the topological entropy scale with $\log(L)$ in 1D?

Tags: topological-order, entanglement-entropy

Why, in one dimension, does the topological entropy scale with the size of system as $S \sim \ln L$, while in a 2D system it scales with $S \sim L$? Why does dimensionality play such an important role here?  I mean, is there any simple but straightforward idea to understand these results?

Comment: I think that the question is way underspecified. You should at least add a reference for the specific $\ln L$ result. I don't think it's obvious how to define a topological entanglement entropy for a generic 1d system, and the $\ln L$ behaviour is usually associated with particular states (e.g. ground, thermal) of models at the critical point, when the result can be derived via CFT and is a "regular" entanglement entropy, not topological.

Comment: The (original)  topological entropy is defined only for 2D space. I do not think the topological entropy can be defined for 1D space. So this question is not a question.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Prof. Wen, the question is not "correct" in itself. Below are some facts:

(1) For both gapped and gapless 1D systems, there is no topological entanglement entropy.
For 1D gapped system, the entanglement entropy is $S\sim L^0$.
For 1D critical system (CFT), the entanglement entorpy is $S\sim\log L$.

(2) For 2D gapped system, the entanglement entropy is $S\sim \alpha L$, i.e., boundary law behavior. In particular, for 2D topological ordered system, there is a subleading universal piece $S\sim \alpha L-\gamma_{top}$, where $\gamma_{top}$ is called the topological entanglement entropy.

(3) For $d$ dimensional gapped system, the leading term is always the boundary law term, i.e., $S\sim L^{d-1}$.

(4) For $d$ dimensional gapless system, the result is very interesting. For example, for free fermions with a finite fermi surface, it is found that $S\sim L^{d-1}\log L$. Intuitively, one can consider the fermi surface in terms of a collection of 1D CFT. There is a good reference on this issue: http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1724.

Answer (score -1):

In a 1D system, all you can do is vary the *size* of a subset, which only ever gives $\propto L$ possibilities. Then the entropy takes the logarithm, and we have $\propto \ln L$.

In higher dimensions however, you can also vary the *shape*, and that is combinatorially much more powerful: you have exponentially many possibilities (think of how you can thread a wire through a grid). The logarithm is then merely able to resolve that into a linear relationship, so it's $S \propto L$ here.

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply. My basic idea is that if I assume I knew nothing about it, then we can assume the topological entropy reads as $S \sim f(L)$, where $L$ is the size of chain (independent of dimension here). Then, for a long enough chain $L_1 + L_2$, we may have $S(L_1 + L_2) = S(L_1) + S(L_2) + \delta S(L_1, L_2)$, where $\delta S$ can be regarded as edge effect. We can see that $S \sim L$ obviously is the solution the above naive picture, but $ln(L)$ is not. I appreciate you answer very well, however, I still fell that this answer may not be easily accepted by a laypersons.

Comment: "Why does the entanglement entropy scale with log(L) in 1D?" is a question. The answer is that  the entanglement entropy does not have to scale with log(L) in 1D. For gapped 1D system, entanglement entropy scales as $L^0$. So the above answer is wrong.

Comment: The above analysis is very interesting. If you assume $L_1 = L_2=L$, then you can find that $\delta S \sim -ln L$, which may become minus infinity when $L$ approach $+\infty$. It means that the edge effect is very strong in 1D system. It become a constant in 2D system, which is expected. Of course I just use this argument to show that our understanding of this issue still need to be improved.

Comment: Thanks Prof. Wen.  This make sense. So how to determine  $L^0$, or what's the basic meaning of $L^0$ here?

Comment: $L^0$ means "does not depend on $L$ in thge large $L$ limit"